# R: editing y axis in ggplot2: highlight characters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 and need to edit the scale of the y axis. More precisely, I need to have a yellow background for the values, as if it was highlighted with a marking pin. I tried to do so with

```
+ theme(axis.text.y=element_text(colour="#00669C"))
```

where I can, however, only edit the text colour, but not its background.

Here's a simplistic version of my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(scales)

Date <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), by="months")
x1 <- c(6, 7, 5, 9, 13, 17, 10, 13, 19, 24, 23, 26, 23, 34, 37, 15, 13, 14, 16, 10, 14, 15, 17, 13, 34, 37, 15, 13, 14,
    16, 10, 14, 15, 17, 13, 13, 19, 24, 23, 26, 23, 34, 37, 15, 13, 14, 16, 16, 14, 15, 17, 13, 13, 19, 24, 23, 26, 23,
    34, 37, 15, 13, 14, 16, 16, 17, 18, 15, 7, 18, 14, 15, 17)
df = data.frame(Date, x1)


ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=x1)) + geom_line() +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(5, 40), expand = c(0, 0)) +
scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b. %y")) +
theme_bw() +  
theme(panel.grid.minor =   element_blank(),       
panel.grid.major.x =   element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.y =   element_line(colour = "black",size=0.5),
legend.position="bottom",
legend.title=element_blank(),
legend.direction="vertical",
legend.key= element_blank(),
axis.text.y=element_text(colour="#00669C", hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5),
axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black",  hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5))
```

In the end, my scale should look something like this:

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4104/9au5flxu_png.htm
[image]

Comment: I think you could experiment with plotting rectangles with yellow fill outside the plot (using gridExtra or something), but if this is a one time thing the fastest solution will probably be to edit your image manually.

Comment: @Heroka: You mean using a tool like Inkscape to add the yellow?

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most likely a more succinct way to overwrite the axis grobs; but here is a way that creates rectangles filled with text, and positions them (with a crude manual adjustment) using `annotation_custom()`

Original plot

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=x1)) + geom_line() +
             scale_y_continuous(limits=c(5, 40), expand = c(0, 0)) +
             scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b. %y"))
```

Extract the y-axis labels and fontsize

```
g <- ggplotGrob(p)  
pth <- g$grobs[[grep("axis-l", g$layout$name)]]$children[[2]]$grobs[[1]]
ylb <- as.numeric(pth$label)
fs <- pth$gp$fontsize

# Function to create yellow box with blue text inside
box_fun <- function(txt, fs, col="blue", fill="yellow", 
                            hadj=unit(0.05, "npc"), wadj=unit(0.2, "npc"))
            {
             txtG <- textGrob(txt, just="centre", gp=gpar(fontsize=fs, col=col))
             h <- unit.c(grobHeight(txtG) + hadj)
             w <- unit.c(grobWidth(txtG) + wadj)
             grobTree(rectGrob(height=h, width=w, 
                                gp=gpar(col=fill, fill=fill)), txtG )
            }

# Create seperate grobs for each axis label text
box_g <- Map(box_fun, ylb, fs)

# Add to plot
# Used manual adjustment to get the x and y positions          
newp <- p + lapply(seq(box_g), function(i) 
             annotation_custom(box_g[[i]], 
                xmin=as.numeric(min(Date))-300, xmax=as.numeric(min(Date))-100, 
                ymin=(ylb-5)[i], ymax=(ylb+5)[i])) 


gp <- ggplotGrob(newp + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank()) )
gp$layout$clip[gp$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gp)
```

To give

[image]